# oracle regular expression to format phone number

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I would like to use a case statement and regular expression combination to format phone number which is coming in below format

`+1 (111) 111-1111`  to `111-111-1111`

and when the number of digits count after the first brace(c) is not equal to 10 then null  else populate as is

Could you please provide me some useful Oracle regular expression functions to handle this

Thank you

Comment: I can't tell what the source format is and what he desired format is.

Comment: Does this mean that the number will ALWAYS have a pair of parentheses? What if the input is in the format 343-999-3333 already?

Comment: That's a good question, if the input is already in expected format I have to populate the same value. in case of 343-999-3333 output should be 343-999-3333

Comment: OK, so let's rephrase the question. Can you have invalid phone numbers with TOO MANY digits? For example: an approach could be to count the digits (while disregarding everything else). If there are fewer than 10 digits total, return NULL. Otherwise just format THE LAST TEN **DIGITS** according to the model 111-111-1111. Would that work for you? As you are asking the question right now, (111) 111-1111 will be left as is, not converted to 111-111-1111. Is that what you want?

Comment: Also - can your phone numbers have an extension? For example, 111-111-1111 ext. 2348? Or do you have a separate field for extension? (Which would be the far superior approach.)

Comment: wow, i don't think i could have phrased this question any better than you. That's exactly what i would need. the problem is the application, they have created a text field for phone number in the application.To answer your question there is no seperate extension field. The users would sometimes type in (111) 111-1111 ext 1111 or (111) 111-1111 ExT 1111. I think we should also consider the possibility of the users may add in extension.

Comment: (while disregarding everything else). 
If there are fewer than 10 digits total, return NULL. 
Otherwise just format THE LAST TEN DIGITS according to the model 111-111-1111 
However if the count of digits is more than 11 
we have to ignore extract the 10 digits in between country code and extension

Comment: Would it be a good idea to create a separate thread for this question?

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '+2 (123) 123-4433' from dual union all -- convert
  3     select '22 (23)234-443'    from dual union all -- do not convert
  4     select '-3 (123) 345 2343' from dual union all -- do not convert
  5     select '123 345 565'       from dual union all -- do not convert
  6     select '+c (334) abc-1234' from dual           -- do not convert
  7    )
  8  select col,
  9         case when regexp_like(col, '\+\d \(\d{3}\) \d{3}-\d{4}') then
 10                   replace(substr(col, 5, length(col)), ') ','-')
 11              else col
 12         end result
 13  from test;

COL               RESULT
----------------- ----------------------------------------------------
+2 (123) 123-4433 123-123-4433
22 (23)234-443    22 (23)234-443
-3 (123) 345 2343 -3 (123) 345 2343
123 345 565       123 345 565
+c (334) abc-1234 +c (334) abc-1234

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you @Littlefoot for quick response. I'm looking at the data and I see some weird number like this  +1  5735. Which i would like to ignore. Actually let me modify my question.

Comment: @user1751356 - if your question (after modification) is different from the one you posted originally, it would be better to start another thread with the new question, not to modify the one that already has Answers based on the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `CASE` expression for this. You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` and try to match the entire string. If a match is found, then use back references to reformat the number into the new model. If a match is not found, then the input string is returned as is.

```
with test (col) as
  (select '+2 (123) 123-4433' from dual union all -- convert
   select '22 (23)234-443'    from dual union all -- do not convert
   select '-3 (123) 345 2343' from dual union all -- do not convert
   select '123 345 565'       from dual union all -- do not convert
   select '+c (334) abc-1234' from dual           -- do not convert
  )
select col,
       regexp_replace(col, '^\+\d \((\d{3})\) (\d{3}-\d{4})$', '\1-\2') result
from   test
;

COL               RESULT              
----------------- --------------------
+2 (123) 123-4433 123-123-4433        
22 (23)234-443    22 (23)234-443      
-3 (123) 345 2343 -3 (123) 345 2343   
123 345 565       123 345 565         
+c (334) abc-1234 +c (334) abc-1234
```